# How do you unlock all of the characters?

Tags: ascendant

So in [Ascendant](https://indiegamestand.com/store/1007/ascendant/), there appear to be a bunch of unlockable characters.  Memnon and Theseus are the only two available at the start however.  I played a couple of games and beat the first boss, but didn't unlock any new characters.

How do I unlock the others?

[image: Character selection screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Memnon**: Free.
- **Theseus**: Free.
- **Gilgamesh**: Fought as the 'final' boss in your first 'completion' of the game, unlocked once  beaten.
- **Chulainn**: Fought as a boss in late winter, which is unlocked after beating Gilgamesh on a  previous playthrough, unlocked once beaten.
- **Ghat**: Unlocked once you have equipped 5 different spells, not necessarily in 1 playthrough.
- **Midas**: Unlocked once you have collected 3000(?) combined influence in all your playthroughs.
- **Hanuman**: Fought as the actual final boss within the Astral which is unlocked after beating Chulainn, unlocked once beaten.